# Store data in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coding a to-do list app in flutter but every time I close the app, all my to-do's are gone, and none of them are stored. How do I stop them from disappearing every time I close the app?

Comment: Take a look at shared preferences

Answer (score 1):

In addition with all the other propositions, you can try Isar, which is a NoSQL local database that can be used for all platforms:

https://isar.dev/tutorials/quickstart.html

https://pub.dev/packages/isar

Answer (score 0):

Apps generally store data in temporary storage which destroyed every time yo close the app. in order to save data permanently, you could use [sqflite database](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or [shared_preferences database](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

if you want use shared_preferences, you can do this:
first make class that call StorageManager:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class StorageManager {
  static Future<bool> saveData(String key, dynamic value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.reload();
    if (value is int) {
      prefs.setInt(key, value);
      return true;
    } else if (value is String) {
      prefs.setString(key, value);
      return true;
    } else if (value is bool) {
      prefs.setBool(key, value);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  static Future<dynamic> readData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.reload();
    dynamic obj = prefs.get(key);
    return obj;
  }

  static Future<bool> deleteData(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.remove(key);
  }

  static Future<void> reloadSharedPreferences() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.reload();
  }
}
```

then use it like this:
when you want save some thing in storage call this:

```
await StorageManager.saveData('some unique key', your int or string or bool value);
```

when you want read from storage:

```
var result = await StorageManager.readData('some unique key');
    if (result != null) {
      // use your value
    } else {
      // this means there is no result
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I'm not sure how to use shared preferences

Comment: you can use the example that the package provide and you can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example)

Comment: I've been trying for the past hour but I still can't get it to work, I'm not sure what to do. I am still new to coding, please can you help me

Comment: I update my answer and add some code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite or files. Please refer documentation on cookbooks for either approach.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence

Your other option is to use an external database over the internet

Answer (score 0):

To persist your data (todo list) you can either

1. store data on the users device

You can do this by using a local databases like [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), [sqfentity](https://pub.dev/packages/sqfentity), [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) etc

2. or store the data on the server

Using this option you can either spin up your own server or use some quick serverless solutions like [supabase](https://supabase.com/) or [cloud firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview) from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend  [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) it’s very easy to use and it’s lightweigh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).